# Stata - ODBC stored procedure with parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sas, stata

We have a Stata user trying to pull in data from a parameterized stored procedure. We have shown her how to do it in SAS, but she is a beginner user for SAS.

```
PROC SQL;
    CONNECT TO ODBC (DATASRC='FAC Prod');
    CREATE TABLE ONE AS
        SELECT *
        FROM CONNECTION TO ODBC
        (EXEC FAC.USP_MASTERPATIENT '2014-01-01', '2014-01-05') AS ODBC;
    DISCONNECT FROM ODBC;
QUIT;
```

What code do you need to write to pull in this stored procedure into Stata?

Answer (score 2):

Other people on [Statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general) have reported problems with stored procedures, but I would try something like this first to see if it works:

```
odbc load, exec("
   CREATE TABLE ONE AS (
      SELECT * FROM (EXEC FAC.USP_MASTERPATIENT '2014-01-01', '2014-01-05')
   );
") clear dsn("FAC Prod") sqlshow multistatement;
```

Before this might work, she will certainly need to configure ODBC first. Here are instructions for [Windows](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/configuring-odbc-win/index.html) and [Mac/Unix/Linux](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/configuring-odbc/index.html). The `odbc` commands are documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539681/stata-odbc-stored-procedure-with-parameters/39540571#39540571).

Comment: Thanks for this quick response. We'll get her to try that when she gets back into the office.